# Creating a component that can be utilised by multiple activites

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar that can be used across multiple activities in my app. The progress bar contains some logic such as when to reset, speed of which the progress bar increments etc.

Instead of creating and coding the logic to implement a progress bar in each activity i would like to create it in a separate class but i am unsure of how to do this. I have come across the include tag that allows you to re-use layouts but i am not sure how to implement the logic that accompanies the progress bar. Does anyone have any advice/suggestion as to the best way to approach this?

Comment: You can create it into a custom base Activity and make all your activities extending it. AppCompatActivity <- MyBaseActivity <- All other activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment you can define a custom Activity with methods for showing / hiding progress bar and then make all other activities extending it.

I provide you an example with a custom ProgressDialog:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyProgressDialog mLoader;

    protected void showLoader() {
        if (mLoader == null) {
            mLoader = new MyProgressDialog(this);
        }
        if (!mLoader.isShowing()) {
            mLoader.show();
        }
    }

    protected void hideLoader() {
        if (mLoader != null && mLoader.isShowing()) {
            mLoader.dismiss();
        }     
    }

}

public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    // here you can use showLoader and hideLoader wherever you need

}
```

Of course you can use whatever you want instead of standard ProgressDialog. For example you can define a custom view. What is important is that regardless of how you will implement loader in BaseActivity, modifications will be available to all your activities.

Here it is an example of progress dialog with a simple custom layout.

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.AppTheme_Translucent);
    }

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCancelable(boolean flag) {
        super.setCancelable(flag);
    }

}
```

Here it is `dialog_progress.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_progress_dialog" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:indeterminateTint="#00acff"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here it is `bg_progress_dialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Here it is style to put in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i understand what you have done here in regards how to implement the logic. One thing that i am still unsure about - the XML layout. If i want to create a progress bar that i can use across lots of activities do i have to have a common view that i must use -  as in must i 'extend' a view that contains a progress bar before implementing additional components to it? This is all new to me so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @Perfect_Comment Well, of course it depends on kind of custom component you would like to implement. What you have to do in general is extending an already existing class (which one depends on your needs). For example you can create a class extending `FrameLayout` and inflate layout you want into it. In case of progress indicator maybe it could be better to extend `ProgressDialog` class or even a generic `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @Perfect_Comment I've added code for a sample loader extending `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: I have looker over and researched the answer and it is what i was looking for. I understand now how the custom layout is implemented  I appreciate your help greatly!

Comment: @Perfect_Comment I'm glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Read about [custom view creation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)